# reRender div without going back to the original width

Tags: html, jsf, tomahawk, rerender

I have a side menu in my project with a closing button.

When I press this button the side menu gets closed and the width of my main t:div enlarges.

Now, when I press search button I defined it should reRender the t:div since it changes its conontent but I don't want it to cause the t:div to also return to the original width, I want it to remain in the enlarged width.

How do I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Just rerender its content instead?

Comment: Yes, that's excactly what I need @BalusC